# I need to get the data in a trigger after an api callout with @Future methode

Tags: apex, trigger, api, future

I need to get the fields from the api and update them in the salesforce object , so i need to callout an api . Here is my trigger

```
trigger getEntrepriseData on Account (before insert,before update) {
   EntDataCallout.getEntData();
   System.debug('call from trigger ' + EntDataCallout.logoUrl);
          
}
```

and here is my apex class

```
global class EntDataCallout {
    public static String logoUrl;
    public static String adresse;
    public static String bio  ;
    public static Integer nombreEmp ;
    public static String dateFondationString ;
    public static Date dateFondation ;
    public EntDataCallout()
    {
        
    }
    @future (callout=true)
    private static void getEntData()
    {
  
        // Define the external API URL
        String apiUrl = 'https://salesforce-test-api.onrender.com/entreprise/getData';
        
        // Create an HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        // Create an HTTP object to send the request
        Http http = new Http();
        
        // Send the request and get the response
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        // Check the response status code
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Handle the response data here
            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            
            // Extract the logo_url field
            logoUrl = (String) jsonResponse.get('logo_url');
            System.debug('call from inside class ' + logoUrl);
            adresse = (String) jsonResponse.get('adresse');
            bio = (String) jsonResponse.get('biographie');
            nombreEmp = (Integer) jsonResponse.get('nombre_emp');
            dateFondationString = (String) jsonResponse.get('date_fondation');
            dateFondation = Date.valueOf(dateFondationString);
            
            
            
            // Now you can use the logoUrl variable as needed
           // System.debug('Logo URL: ' + logoUrl);
            // Process the response data as needed
            // You may want to parse the JSON response, update records, etc.
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the request failed
            System.debug('HTTP request failed with status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Callouts cannot be made directly from triggers, that's why you need to go async (`@future`, `Schedulable`, `Batchable`, `Queueable`, or by publishing a `Platform Event`).

The async code runs in a completely different transaction from your trigger. There is no way to get data back from async code into the transaction that caused the async code to be run in the first place.

What you need to do instead is to perform a DML operation (insert, update, delete, etc...) in your async code, after you've made your callout.

e.g.

```java
// Don't use the "global" access modifier unless you need to
// For calling your own code from your own trigger, "public" is appropriate
public class AFutureCallout {

    // Must be public for you to be able to call this method from outside of this class
    // You also generally want to pass record Ids in so you can perform DML
    //   after the callout
    @future(callout=true)
    public static doCallout(List<Id> recordIdList) {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        // Don't forget to add the url in a Remote Site Setting in your org!
        // Otherwise, Salesforce will not allow the callout
        // Named Credentials are another option
        req.setEndpoint('<some url here>');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            List<Some_SObject__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Some_SObject__c>();
    
            for(Id recId :recordIdList) {
                // One of Salesforce's golden rules is to (basically) never
                //   have DML or queries inside of a loop
                // Add things to a collection, then do the DML outside of the loop
                recordsToUpdate.add(new Some_SObject__c(
                    Id = recId,
                    Some_Field__c = response.getBody()
                ));
            }

            update recordsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that's just a basic example. The code you'll actually need to use will likely be different. Right now, you would be making this callout every single time an Account is inserted or updated (and multiple times for a single insert/update if you're working on more than 200 records at a time. Salesforce breaks DML operations into chunks of 200 records).

If your callout doesn't depend on data specific to the records going through the trigger (and right now it appears that it doesn't depend on specific record data), then it'd likely be wiser to:

- Use a `Scheduleable` class to fetch data once (say, once per day)
- Store the results in the `PlatformCache` or in a dedicated SObject
- Then use a `Batchable` class to determine which records need to be updated, and update them

Comment: In terms of using `@Future` methods from a trigger, please [read this](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) as to why you should not and [see an example](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) of how you can replace this with Platform Events that result in a callout.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer ..